# Woocommerce USPS

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, usps

Just want to ask on how to add this in `Woocommerce Shipping`

see attached.

This is the dimension the box:

> Small-FRB
>
> ID: 5 3/8 x 8 5/8 x 1 5/8
>
> OD: 8 11/16 x 5 7/16 x 1 3/4
>
> ODCUFT: 0.044

What is the meaning of `ID, OD, ODCUFT in USPS`?

Thanks for the help

[image]

Comment: Inside Dimension, Outside Dimension..

Comment: Thanks, how to add it in Woocommerce shipping thanks